# Just installed Juypter on Windows 10 fails to launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have reinstalled all the packages multiple times as well as my computer, pls help

I recieve the following error after trying to launch Juypter Lab through cmd:

````
C:\Users\user>jupyter lab

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1720, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 404, in init_webapp
    super().init_webapp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1482, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError```
````

Comment: Please add all relevant information - platform, python version Jupyter version, pip version, package list (other packages can collide).

Comment: Please tell us what version of python you're using. There seems to be a [case](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4613) that is caused by python version, so I think it might be related.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first run this code in CMD

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

then after that check whether If you have Python 3 installed then try

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

after that Type "jupyter notebook"

on the website it is mentioned as

> Because JupyterLab is a server extension of the classic Jupyter Notebook server, you can launch JupyterLab by calling jupyter notebook and visiting the /lab URL: http(s):////lab

it will work ,id did for me.

[image]

Comment: OP is trying to run JupyterLab, not notebook

Comment: on the website it is mentioned as" Because JupyterLab is a server extension of the classic Jupyter Notebook server, you can launch JupyterLab by calling jupyter notebook and visiting the /lab URL:http(s)://<server:port>/<lab-location>/lab".

Comment: And what version of python are you using?

Comment: i am using python 3.8

Comment: Yeah could it be because we'rem using 3.8? I just recently thought of downgrading to 3.7, have yet to try it though

Answer (score 0):

on the website it is mentioned as" Because JupyterLab is a server extension of the classic Jupyter Notebook server, 
you can launch JupyterLab by calling jupyter notebook and visiting the /lab URL:
    `http(s)://<server:port>/<lab-location>/lab`.